# Zend_Db_Adapter fetchOne returns OCI-Lob object instead of string

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, fetch, clob

I am using **Zend Framework** and **Oracle** and I am trying to receive single value from database like this:

```
$userId = (int) $this->_getParam('userId');

// CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
//    "MEMEBER_ID" NUMBER,
//    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
//    "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
//    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
//    "ABOUT" CLOB
// )

$sql = 'SELECT about FROM members WHERE id = :userId';

$binds = array (
   'userId' => $userId
);

$about = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchOne($sql, $binds);
```

According to [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchone), `fetchOne()` should return string, but when I dump returned value, it looks like this:

```
object(OCI-Lob)#1161 (1) {
  ["descriptor"] => resource(209) of type (oci8 descriptor)
}
```

As you can see, object is returned, which is against the manual - "*it returns only a single scalar value, **not an array or an object***."

How can I convert this to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `CLOB` data type used in column `about`. Answer fot this is given in [notes for Oracle adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.oracle), especially:

> By default, LOB fields are returned as OCI-Lob objects. You could retrieve them as string for all requests by using driver options 'lob_as_string' or for particular request by using setLobAsString(boolean) on adapter or on statement.

So the solution is really simple, just call `setLobAsString(true)` before `fetchOne()` like this:

```
$about = Zend_Registry::get('db')->setLobAsString(true)->fetchOne($sql, $binds);

echo $about; // string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome of this problem by adding 1 line in your application.ini

please add

```
resources.db.params.driver_options.lob_as_string=true
```

this will convert lob to string automatically. you don't have to write anything else in Zend.